# It won't read certain values of a textbox that are between what I specify in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a button that when you click it, adds +1 to a textbox value, and when you click another button, it should see if the first text box, the clicks box, is under or over 50. If the textbox value is over 50, it will take 50 clicks away, and add +5 gold to the second text box. And if the value is under 50, it will do nothing to the values and just say "Insufficient amount of clicks, sorry!"

Now the problem is, if the click value is specifically 7, it will take 50 clicks and add 5 gold, and leave you with -43 clicks. The point of the if statement in javascript, is that it shouldn't let any values go below 0. Now if the click value gets passed 200, it says "Insufficient amount of clicks, sorry!" I just want to know whats wrong with my code, so I'm going to paste my javascript and my buttons here, thanks for the help!

```
<script>
function clk1(){
    document.f1.t1.value += '+1';
    document.f1.t1.value = eval(f1.t1.value);
}
function prz1(){
    var x=document.f1.t1.value;
    if (x >= "50"){
        document.f1.t1.value += '-50';
        document.f1.t1.value = eval(f1.t1.value);
        document.f1.g1.value += '+5';
        document.f1.g1.value = eval(f1.g1.value);
    }
    else if (x <= "50"){
        alert("Insufficient amount of clicks, sorry!");
    }
}
function prz2(){

}
</script>

Clicks: <input type="text" value="0" name="t1" id="a1" disabled><br>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" id="a1" onClick="clk1()"><br>
Gold: <input type="text" value="0" name="g1" id="a1" disabled><br>
Cost: 50 Clicks <input type="button" value="5 gold" id="a1" onClick="prz1()"><br>
Cost: 100 Clicks <input type="button" value="10 gold" id="a1" onClick="prz2()"><br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing strings, not numbers. Strings are compared in alphanumeric order. So:

```
"200" > "50"
```

is false. Because `2` comes before `5`.

And:

```
"7" > "50"
```

Is true because `7` comes after `5`.

You need to convert all your strings to numbers if you want to compare them numerically.

For example:

```
    var x = parseInt(document.f1.t1.value, 10);
    if (x >= 50){
        //....
    }
```

`parseInt` will convert your string into a number in the base specified (10 in this case).

Also you can get rid of all those `eval` statements once you are doing math with actual numbers. Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/X7kCF/

```
function clk1() {
    document.f1.t1.value = parseInt(document.f1.t1.value, 10) + 1;
}

function prz1() {
    var x = parseInt(document.f1.t1.value, 10);
    if (x >= 50) {
        document.f1.t1.value = x - 50;
        document.f1.g1.value = parseInt(document.f1.g1.value, 10) + 5;
    } else {
        alert("Insufficient amount of clicks, sorry!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the quotes off where you are checking the value:
if (x >= 50)

You're comparing an integer to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is the following:

```
        function increaseClickCount() {
            var clickCountField = document.getElementById('clickAmount');
            var currentClicks = parseFloat(clickCountField.value);
            currentClicks = currentClicks + 1;
            clickCountField.value = currentClicks;
        }

        function exchangeToGold() {
            var clickCountField = document.getElementById('clickAmount');
            var currentClicks = parseFloat(clickCountField.value);
            if (currentClicks > 50) {
                currentClicks = currentClicks - 50;
                var goldCountField = document.getElementById('goldAmount');
                var currentGold = parseFloat(goldCountField.value);
                currentGold = currentGold + 1;
                goldCountField.value = currentGold;
            } else {
                alert('Insufficient amount of clicks, sorry!');
            }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
Clicks: <input type="text" value="0" name="t1" id="clickAmount" disabled><br>

<input type="button" value="Click me!" id="a1" onClick="increaseClickCount()"><br>

Gold: <input type="text" value="0" name="g1" id="goldAmount" disabled><br>

Cost: 50 Clicks <input type="button" value="5 gold" id="a1" onClick="exchangeToGold()"><br>
```

What you were doing wrong, is comparing strings to integers. When working with numbers, I always prefer to parse the variable to an integer (or float) and then process it.